# Cleaning up broken XML in Python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

A server I don't control sends broken XML with characters such as '>', '&', '<' etc. in attributes and text.

A small sample:

```
<StockFormula Description="" Name="F_Î”TURN" RankType="Higher" Scope="Universe" Weight="10.86%">
    <Formula>AstTurnTTM>AstTurnPTM</Formula>
</StockFormula>
<Composite Name="Piotroski & Trends - <11@4w600k 70b" Weight="0%" RankType="Higher">
</Composite>
```

I settled on using the lxml module because it is case sensitive, is very fast and gets the job done.

How would I go about fixing up this type of XML? Basically, I am trying to replace all occurrences of the invalid characters with the proper escape sequences.

```
import re

broken = '<StockFormula Description="" Name="F_Î”TURN" RankType="Higher" Scope="Universe" Weight="10.86%">\n<Formula>AstTurnTTM>AstTurnPTM</Formula>\n<Composite Name="Piotroski & Trends - <11@4w600k 70b" Weight="0%" RankType="Higher">\n</Composite>'
print re.sub(r'(.*Name=".*)&(")', r'\g<1>&gt;\g<2>', broken)
```

Output:

```
<StockFormula Description="" Name="F_ÃŽâ€TURN" RankType="Higher" Scope="Universe" Weight="10.86%">
    <Formula>AstTurnTTM>AstTurnPTM</Formula>
</StockFormula>
<Composite Name="Piotroski & Trends - <11@4w600k 70b" Weight="0%" RankType="Higher">
</Composite>
```

Answer (score 3):

First, realize no XML parser can help you with "broken XML."  XML parsers only operate over XML, which by definition must be **[well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085)**.

Second, it is not possible to repair "broken XML" in the general case.  There are no rules governing "broken XML."  Without a clear definition of "broken XML," you cannot be guaranteed to be able to process it and convert it to real XML.

That said, [HTML Tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/) does a decent job of repairing (X)HTML, and it has limited capabilities for repairing XML as well.  It's your best bet for automated repair of "broken XML."  There is a Python package, [PyTidyLib](http://countergram.com/open-source/pytidylib/docs/index.html), which wraps the HTML Tidy library.

Comment: I installed PyTidyLib using pip. But when I tried to run the [Small example of use](http://countergram.com/open-source/pytidylib/docs/index.html) I got AttributeError: `'Tidy' object has no attribute '_tidy'`

Comment: Carefully follow the instructions for [**Installing HTML Tidy**](http://countergram.com/open-source/pytidylib/docs/index.html#installing-html-tidy).  If that doesn't help, I have no further guidance to offer.  Perhaps ask a new question about getting PyTidyLib to work, or try using HTML Tidy directly without PyTidyLib.  Good luck.